# Disable all but one core via bash command

Tags: bash, ssh, benchmarking, multicore

Is there a way to switch off one of the cores of a dual core machine via a bash command?
I am trying to compare the performance of different machines and I want to use only one core in each of the machines. Is there a way to do that? (Note that I am doing this via SSH, so please tell me the options which will work via SSH. I do have root privileges though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
root# echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
root# dmesg | tail | grep CPU
[23164.810371] CPU 1 is now offline
```

Redirection is done by the shell so if you need to use sudo, run it like this

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online'
```

If you're on a tilera ;)

```
root# for i in $(seq 1 99); do echo 0 >/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/online; done
```

Comment: +1 because it's sad to see accepted answers without any upvote. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the affinity of the various commands you run, in order to force them to be scheduled on a single core.

Comment: How do I do that?
Also I just saw a command which seems to do what I want -

disable second core:
`echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online`

re-enable second core:
`echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online`

Comment: That depends on the OS in question.